# Thoughts on how to implement paging for a detail page

Tags: asp.net

I am curious as to what people would thing is the best way to implement this.

On my overview page, I have a data grid which is sortable and has custom filtering written for it. When you click on an item in the grid, it loads a separate page with details.

I would like to implement result paging through on the detail page keeping in the same order as the previous page data grid.

Now I've thought of a few ways to do this:

- Change the link to be a postback and handle the sort order programatically
- Sort filter and sort settings on application of the settings in the session
- Pass the filter and sort settings on the query string to the detail page

None of these seem very clean to me, and option 3 is the only cogent option I've thought of.

Am I missing something? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is preferable to have **url access** to any details view that may be needed independently of the master.

Of course, you can have both postback and GET access, but begin with the url and querystring. I have had to fix numerous postback-only views to support direct urls, when the need has eventually arised.

If the filters and sort order are very complex and would require an elaborate querystring parameter scheme, I would think hard what is really needed for url access. Complex settings are best passed in a serializable .NET object in the Session or ViewState. You'll get .NET type safety and avoid error-prone querystring/form/cookie parsing. Session would be better if you need to pass these settings from another page of the application.